# When checkbox in Column H is checked, have Yes/No pop-up selection change cell color in Column B

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, popup

I have a spreadsheet where I track my daily orders. I include the sales order number, delivery order number, customer code, order total, then I have checkboxes for delivery or pickup, terms or COD, etc.

We frequently have customers with terms have their orders go on credit hold for review for someone at corporate to release.

What I have been trying to figure out is when I check the box for terms in Column H, I want a Yes/No alert pop-up that asks if the order is on hold. If the order is on hold and I click "Yes" I want the sales order number cell in Column B to change to yellow.

When I am entering and recording orders, I typically first check the terms or COD boxes, then enter the sales order number. So, ideally, I want to have conditions in place where if the terms box is checked and then a number is entered in the sales order cell and I hit enter, the alert will then pop-up and clicking yes will change the color of the cell I just entered the number in.

[Order Entry Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4wPu.png)

This is what I currently have:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(
    (ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 8 & ss.getRange(ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()).getValue() == 'TRUE') &&
    (ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 2 & ss.getRange(ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()).getValue() (!cell.isBlank()))
    );

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     '⚠️ Is the order on hold?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();
    var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
    currentCell.setBackground('#ffff00');
  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();
    var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
    currentCell.setBackground('BACKGROUND');
  }
}
```

It kind of works, but the pop-up comes up when I check or uncheck the box for "NET", and also when I enter and delete a sales order number

Comment: `when I check the box for terms in Column H, I want a Yes/No alert pop-up` ... `if the terms box is checked and then a number is entered in the sales order cell and I hit enter, the alert will then pop-up`, these two statements involve two separate/different issues, are you looking to solve both of them?

Comment: Might I suggest.  Have another column with the results of your Yes/No query.  If it is true use conditional formatting to change the color of the cell.  Otherwise you have to go back and clear the color format of the cells whose status changes.

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 yes I am trying to solve them both, or if it is simpler, if I just click the terms box for any row, the cell in column B of the same row will change color based on the pop-up selection value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample onEdit script that will detect the checkbox in column H being clicked.  And if TRUE will display an alert dialog to ask if the order should be placed on hold.  And change cell in column B to yellow.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
    if( e.range.getColumn() === 8 ) {
      if( e.value === "TRUE" ) {
        let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        let button = ui.alert("Place order on hold",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
        if( button = ui.Button.YES ) {
          e.range.offset(0,-6).setBackground("yellow");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference

- [onEdit() event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [SpreadsheetApp.UI()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html)
- [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))

Answer (score 0):

#### Order Entry Form

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 8 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("Flag1");
    let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(["YES","NO"]).build();
    e.range.offset(0,-6).setDataValidation(rule);
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "YES") {
    e.source.toast("Flag2")
    e.range.setBackground("yellow");
  }
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "NO") {
    e.source.toast("Flag3")
    e.range.setBackground("white");
  }
}
```

Change Sheet Name

Demo:

[image]